# Flutter workmanager plugin doesn't work with Health plugin

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous

I am currently facing challenges integrating the Health Factory plugin with the Workmanager package in my Flutter application. The goal is to fetch health data, specifically step counts, using the Health Factory plugin within a background task scheduled by Workmanager.

```
void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager().executeTask((task, inputData) async {
    // Your task implementation goes here
    // This method will be called when a scheduled task is triggered
    HealthFactory health = HealthFactory();
    List<HealthDataPoint> healthDataList;

    healthDataList = await health.getHealthDataFromTypes(
        DateTime(2024, 03, 01, 10, 22), DateTime.now(), [HealthDataType.STEPS]);
    print(healthDataList);

    return Future.value(true);
  });
}
```

I'm not able to successfully retrieve the health data using the Health Factory plugin within the Workmanager background task. The background task appears to be executing, but the health data is not being fetched as expected.it always returns empty list.